# What's the difference between $J_1=A\otimes B$ , and $J_2=A\otimes I_m+I_n\otimes B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Consider operator $A,B$ and its tensor product $J_1=A\otimes B$ , and $J_2=A\otimes I_m+I_n\otimes B$ where $n$ and $m$ were dimension of $A$ and $B$.

It's easy to see that $J_1,J_2$ commute and thus share the same eigenstates.

Prove/disprove that there's a one to one correspondence between the eigenvalue of $J_1$ and $J_2$ in the sence of order and degeneracy.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between the title of your post and the rest of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows: let $J_3 = \exp(J_2)$, where $\exp$ denotes the matrix exponential.  We compute
$$
J_3 = \exp(A\otimes I_m+I_n\otimes B) = \exp(A) \otimes \exp(B).
$$
It now suffices to show that that there's a one to one correspondence between the eigenvalues of $J_2$ and $J_3$, and also a one to one correspondence between the eigenvalues of $J_3$ and $J_1$.